# Scanning two characters for a switch case in C

Tags: c, string, char, switch-statement, case

So I'm writing a program for a text editor and I have a switch statement set up so that when someone enters in a specific character it will call a function. for example if they enter '?' it will present a help menu by calling the function help() like so

```
scanf("%c", &choice);
switch(choice)
{
case '?':
help();
```

my problem is that some of the choices have two characters, for example to create a new file they would have to enter the characters NF. How would I go about implementing this in a case? do I need " "? also should choice be scanned as a string instead of a character?

```
case "NF":
newFile();
```

Comment: Use `%s` in the `scanf()` format string, or `fgets()` with `sscanf()`. You will need to use `strcmp()` since you can't `switch()` on a string.

Answer (score 1):

When you have one character, you can make a decision based on its value, using `switch` statement. Because its actual value is a one-byte unsigned integer. But here you have two characters and you can't use `switch`.
You have to use `if..else..else..`

```
if (!strcmp(choice, "NF")) {
    // deal with NF
} else if (!strcmp(size, "SomethingElse")) {
    // deal with it
} // and so on
```